# JavaScript: How to do grep nice grep searches now that I have a bundle.js file?

Tags: javascript, debugging, grep, reactjs, webpack

Problem: Debugging and searching program for files that contain strings

I like using grep string searches to hunt down methods and variables in a program.

Since I've been bundling with webpack though, I have this bundle.js file that  totally fills my `grep -r "searchstring"` with a bunch of garbage that makes it hard to look for the results.

Have you guys found any tricks out there to get around that?

Comment: are you searching minified file? use full version.

Comment: @webduvet I'm creating it like this with webpack                                    entry: "./js/app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "js/bundle.js"
  }                                                                                                                                      So I don't think I've explicitly set it to be minfied (the file doesn't look to be entirely crunched so I'm not sure that is).